# How can i assign specific record type to opportunity while converting lead via database.LeadConvert

Tags: opportunity, record-type, lead-conversion

I have a trigger on events which on receiving data creates leads and then converts it to Opportunity.
The problem is the record type is assigned to specific profile level default for the user that is being used as integration user, how can i assign record type for opportunity in the apex code while converting the lead.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done as part of the `leadConvert` method, so you'll have to write separate automation on the Lead object that fires when the lead conversion is complete.  You can then reference the `ConvertedOpportunityId` field in the Lead to find the opp and change the record type.

See [Lead Object documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) for info on `IsConverted` and `ConvertedOpportunityId` fields.